# Out of theory pgns collection

Tags: opening

Looking for pgn files that end in taking the most popular openings out of theory.

Something like
1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. a3

Where I can practice them in chessable.com

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. What's the point of having a PGN that ends 3.a3? Would you also want one that goes 3.h3, and 3.a4, etc?

Comment: Something that takes the game out of theory but is profalactic against the main line and still a good move but not nessasarily  the best move.

Comment: But there are at least three main line continuations for white here (Nc3, Nf3, g3), with multiple replies to each like ...c5, ...d5, ...Bb4, ...b6, depending. 3.a3 only prevents one, I'd say it's a bad move. So you're basically asking for a list of early deviaitions from theory that might be playable? That's a very broad question.

Comment: Yes, exactly an early deviation from theory but but sill a good move. I want a sort of database of these, to get a feel for it. Usually around 80 lines is enough for chessable.com

Comment: If there was a list of games, move by move, with good quality moves out of main lines - wouldn't it be a theory already? I think you want to solve a wrong problem!

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand what you want, but www.365chess.com might do what you want. Using the opening explorer it has 960 games starting with the above line, for example, and you can download them as a compressed pgn. Might need to be a member to do this, though.

Comment: Yes. I was looking for something smaller and curated to span popular openings.

Comment: You can access the "Unorthodox Chess Openings" on Yahoo Groups. Had several publications of surprise systems that avoid opening theory. A recomended reading. Even Clyde Nakamura contributed some articles, like "The Blackburne-Kloosterboer Gambit".

Comment: Another source of interest, could be books with the title "Errors in the openings" and very old opening books, containing lines that are unusual today.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is about Chessable, I thought I'd pitch in :) If you use [Chessable's Explorer Tool](https://www.chessable.com/explore/) you will be able to navigate to a position such as

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6

and then see which options are available to you and their win rate.

For instance 3. a3 scores 36% W, 22% D, 42% B, so if you are White, you can see it would not be a good opening to pick.

By browsing like this, you can find good options and add them to your repertoire and try to avoid complex theory. You can also turn the engine on that page and check the lines with the Engine for possible continuations.

However, in my opinion, if you want to play out of theory the best thing is to pick some openings that are known for their relative lack of theory and see if a complete book exists on it (free or otherwise). For instance, Fianchetto systems or the London System come to mind as ways to play where you can play without much theory.

As Black, I've had a Master play things like the Pirc/Modern against me where they "wait" on the third rank for you. They did not seem to be playing theory but rather just a standard set of moves (fianchetto a bishop, play e6, etc.). I had a better position but since they took me out of theory into murky waters, eventually their time advantage paid off, and I lost. Presumably, this is what you are trying to do? :)

Having said all that, this week we are releasing a new book by a renowned French chess coach that has relatively little theory and guides you to sound openings where your opponent can quickly get in trouble. So stay tuned and look out for it!

Answer (score 1):

A chess engine with a good opening book might be a better source to identify sidelines or novelties.  For example, with Rybka you can view the opening book with it's list of moves while putting the engine on infinite analysis and see what moves it is looking at that aren't in the book list.
You can even do "deep position analysis" which I think generates a pgn with a huge width of moves -- you could then trim out the book lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you could also check out some computer chess competitions (e.g. the  Top Chess Engine Championship, TCEC) that don't use opening books.

Answer (score -1):

Chesstempo.com's database can help you with that.